# Git clone using ssh does not work with message "git@github.com: No such file or directory"

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, clone

I'm trying to clone a private Github repo from my linux Mint computer using ssh.
I have created a private/public key pair and registered it with Github (different than the default id_rsa).
When I try `ssh -vT git@github.com` , I have successful authentication.

But when I make a git clone using the URL given by GitHub, I get the following error :

```
git clone git@github.com:benblan/{private_repo}.git
Cloning into '{private_repo}'...
git@github.com: No such file or directory
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The ssh-agent is running.

```
ps -eaf | grep ssh
benblan      1525    1455  0 09:58 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/im-launch cinnamon-session-cinnamon
benblan      2109    1452  0 09:59 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -D -a /run/user/1000/keyring/.ssh
```

The only thing I see is that when I echo the variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK, I have a different path : /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh (no dot in front of ssh).

I could use HTTPS with Personal Access Token, but I wanted to make the ssh connection work.

Any idea?

Comment: What gives `git clone -v git@github.com:benblan/{private_repo}.git`?

Comment: It's the same message that without the -v option.
I also tried setting GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -v, but no additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double-check your ssh client is fully installed/up-to-date:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openssh-client
```

And specify the full path for ssh and your key:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="/usr/bin/ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Then try again.

---

The alternative would be to reference the same private key by a `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host gh
  Hostname github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/path/to/private_key
```

And

```
git clone gh:benblan/{private_repo}.git
```

Comment: Hi, I checked if the client was up to date and it was already ok. Then the GIT_SSH_COMMAND worked. For information, I didn't use the id_rsa but another key pair I had created specifically.
Thanks!

Comment: @benblan Great, well done. Yes, `~/.ssh/id_rsa`  was an example, and you indeed have to replace it by your actual private key filename.